# 2K3 Server Standaard Edition Domain Controller Setup

Tags: windows-server-2003

Im trying to setup a domain controller for my server and I am trying to do it offline with no internet connection is this possible? If so why do I keep getting a message saying Configure TCP/IP even though I have already set it up?

Comment: More detail needed. Where are you seeing this message?

Answer (score 2):

Because WIndwos DOmains - since bout 2000 or even earlier - use TCP.

It is assumed that:

- regardless whether you have internet or not, you have a network. You know, more than 2 computers.
- you use TCP as network protocol.

As such, it is mandatory to configure TCP properly.